# How to Store Environment Variables in Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables, engineyard

For Ruby on Rails applications, I've noticed that I don't have the option to do a `ENV['NUCLEAR_LAUNCH_CODES'] = 12345` anywhere unlike Heroku.

For a Rails 3.2.17 application, does anyone know what the best practice is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables with [`figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem.

Comment: Hey, was my suggestion useful?

Comment: Yes it was actually. I've got a new branch set up and I'm battle testing it on development.

Comment: I've run into this [new issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569696/how-to-tell-engine-yard-to-not-delete-a-file-in-the-gitignore). You wouldn't happen to know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this recipe](https://github.com/engineyard/ey-cloud-recipes/tree/master/cookbooks/env_vars) from Engine Yard.

If you have some sensitive data in your environment vars, the custom recipe allow you to manage your vars outside your application repos.

Your application can use environment vars configured in the recipe after you apply the recipe.

But if you use `rails console` via ssh, you have to explicitly read and execute the config file before you enter a console.

```
source /data/YOUR_APP_NAME/shared/config/env.custom
bundle exec rails console
```