# How to Tell Engine Yard to Not Delete a File in the .gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, engineyard

To give you some context, I'm trying to use [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to safely add in environment variables without having to worry about security risks. The problem is is that I can't seem to get Engine Yard to play nice with production.

I went and did a `touch application.yml` and then `vim application.yml`, <kbd>i</kbd>, and then <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to insert that api keys and what not. I know the `ENV['VARIABLES']` work because of development and all my rspec and cucumber tests (which utilize the APIs), passed.

When I've got everything ready, I add within the `.gitignore`:

```
# Ignore application configuration
/config/application.yml
```

Afterwards, I deploy the site. I open it up and data isn't going to the APIs anymore. OK...

`cd` into config and discover `application.yml` isn't there anymore. Paste it back in... Redeploy the site since now it understands it has to ignore that file and I'm not seeing changes on production. Check back... and its gone again!

Stumped on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting a file into your deployed application's filesystem will not work because you get a clean environment each time you deploy. EngineYard cannot know that you want that particular file copied to that particular location without a little bit of extra work.

Their [official recommendation](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/36999448-Environment-Variables-and-Why-You-Shouldn-t-Use-Them) is to put your YAML configuration files in `/data/<app>/shared/config` and symlink them to `/data/<app>/current/config` each time you deploy using [deploy hooks](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21016568-Use-Deploy-Hooks).